# Does it really matter which starter you pick?

Tags: pokemon-go

Your starter pokemon become useless immediately when you level up and catch stronger pokemon. Does picking a starter pokemon give you some kind of bonus at some things? Or is it just an irrelevant tutorial thing?

Comment: The only reason to pick one over the others I've seen is that, in my region, charmanders seem to be significantly rarer than squirtle/bulbasaur.

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't really matter which starter you pick, as you can catch all of the starters in the wild, or hatch them from eggs. It is just an ode to how all Pokémon games start, and part of the very brief tutorial thing. You can also just walk away from the 3 starters and get a Pikachu as a starter instead if you wish.

Comment: I will say this: I've yet to find a Charmander, and finding Bulbasaurs, Squirtles, and Pikachus is pretty difficult for me. I have a few, but not nearly enough to evolve any of them.

Comment: @Ellesedil I've found 3 Charmanders, 3 Bulbasaurs, 5 Pikachus, and a Charzard.

Comment: Did you catch the Charizard?

Comment: @Dragonrage what kind of a place did you find the Charizard at?

Comment: @Andrew downtown in the city, but it was 3 steps away, and I had to go in for work, so I wasn't able to track him down.

Comment: @Dragonrage dang, that's rough. rarest thing i've managed to come across so far and catch was Scyther

Comment: @Andrew there is a small lake near my house and my brother saw a blastoise there. He didn't catch it cause he ran out of pokeballs  >.> Also the rarest one I have seen is a dratini

Answer (score 5):

Your starters are very weak in the beginning and you will find stronger pokemon really quickly and be able to evolve them a lot earlier than your starter. Personally I started with a Squirtle but I've found significantly more Bulbasaurs in the wild and ended up evolving an Ivysaur before getting my Squirtle evolution. For a while my starter was actually in my bottom 10 weakest pokemon out of like 40 or so pokemon.

You probably won't even begin to see the starter pokemon regularly until you hit around trainer level 12ish which is important because it means you can't evolve them early.

Comment: Curious to see if there's any source for that last comment- I've found 2 squirtles, one at lv6 and one at lv14. Am currently lv15, with no more starter luck than I've had at any time previously :)

Comment: I suppose that's just due to variance, I was only going off of my own experience but I could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, no. Your starter does not matter much. Your starter will be very weak and you will find a replacement very soon after if you hatch eggs. Sadly, your starter will almost certainly be transferred to the meatgrinder and fed to something stronger you find down the line. (Then again, that's entirely your decision!)

But no, your starter is hardly going to be unique or noteworthy in the long-run.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, No.

But since terrain and climates can affect what Pokemon you encounter (See [Does terrain matter or are the Pokémon's randomly grouped?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/273417/120411)) it may be slightly more beneficial to pick a starting pokemon that has less probability of being spawned near your area.

All 4 starters are available from 2.0km eggs also.